# Retaining an SSH session across multiple API calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, netmiko

So interesting situation here. Currently I have a simple Flask API that connects to a network device on the backend and retrieves command output.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def _execute_cli(self, opt, command):
        """
           Internal method to create netmiko connection and
           execute command.
        """
        try:
            net_connect = ConnectHandler(**opt)
            cli_output = (net_connect.send_command(command))
        except (NetMikoTimeoutException, NetMikoAuthenticationException,) as e:
            reason = e.message
            raise ValueError('Failed to execute cli on %s due to %s', opt['ip'], reason)
        except SSHException as e:
            reason = e.message
            raise ValueError('Failed to execute cli on %s due to %s', opt['ip'], reason)
        except Exception as e:
            reason = e.message
            raise ValueError('Failed to execute cli on %s due to %s', opt['ip'], reason)
        return cli_output


def disconnect(connection):
    connection.disconnect()
```

Each command output is cached locally for a period of time. The problem is, someone could make multiple connections simultaneously, and a device has a connection limit (Let's say 7). What happens is if too many calls are made, an SSH connection issue occurs because max connections have been reached.

What I'm looking to do is retain a single session across these API calls for a device for a specified period of time (Let's say, 5 minutes), and that way I'm not filling up the connections on the device.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i am not sure what did you mean by "retain a single session across these API calls". But maybe you can do something like this.

Create a dictionary for all devices and and their user amount in every 5 min. for example:

`self.users = {device:0 for device in devices}`

and then whenever `_execute_cli()` function called, you can check the amount of users in device before sending commands(in cisco the command is 'show users') and update the variable `self.users[device] = some_number`.

So you can simply check like like:

```
if self.users[device] < 7:
    try:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**opt)
        cli_output = (net_connect.send_command(command))
...
```